# Python: Remove from excel chart legend if value==0

Tags: python, excel, charts, xlsxwriter

I am making a pie chart using xlsxwriter. I have lots of rows where the value is zero for the column I want to plot. Is it possible to remove from the legend if value is zero?
So For example, in the following case I do not want to show Umbro and Fila in the legend
[image]

What should my `add_series` function look like?
I don't see anything here: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pandas-xlsxwriter-charts/latest/pandas-xlsxwriter-charts.pdf

Comment: FWIW, don't use pie charts if you have more than three data points. There are better charts to do that, for example horizontal bars. Sort the data to plot the highest value at the top. If you want, filter out zeros,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XlsxWriter API for removing series names from a chart legend is the `delete_series` property of `set_legend()`, [see the XlsxWriter docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2IiK.png):

```
# Delete/hide series index 0 and 2 from the legend.
# i.e., Series 1 and 3 from a 3 series chart.
chart.set_legend({'delete_series': [0, 2]})
```

[image]

You will need to determine which series items have a zero value.

Note, in order to avoid, or add, confusion it is worth pointing out that Pie charts in Excel are a little different from other charts. Pie charts refer to each point in a series as if it is itself a series. That is why each point appears on the legend.

Comment: Thanks! can I send it a list or an array of indexes to delete? Tried various ways but can't seem to send it a list that is deleted. Also looping through a list for individual arrays also only seems to implement the last deletion

Comment: I don't quite understand. The above example uses a list, no? Are you asking how to generate the list? I'd probably use a list comprehension to generate the list. Maybe ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Hi JMC, please help with Pie chart to suppress zero values along with the category - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069256/how-to-suppress-category-in-excel-pie-chart-for-zero-values