# How to suppress Category in Excel Pie Chart for zero values?

Tags: excel, pie-chart

The data source for the Pie chart is Pivot table, with values set as % of column total. I am able to suppress the data values in the Pie chart by custom formatting number in Data labels, as #. But this still leaves Category name visible. Please advise how to suppress the Category name.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pie charts will ignore categories with value set to #N/A so an if statement that switches zeros to NA() will do this.

Comment: Data values come from Column: C of the image. How can I set value to #N/A in Pivot table field list- value field settings?